# How to minify knockoutjs code files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, minify

I have added knockout js files in Javascript Bundles & at release mode these are minified. Everything is working fine in debug mode. But when optimizations are on & JsBundles are minified automatically by Visual Studio it changes parameters name which starts causing issues. Example:

**minified file after Prettify**

```
function ProgramViewModel() {
  var n = this;
  n.Programs = ko.observableArray([]);
  n.SelectProgramForDetails = ko.observable('');
  n.SelectedProgramList = ko.observableArray([]);
  n.RequestedPrograms = ko.observableArray([]);
  n.SelectedPrograms = ko.observableArray([]);
  n.SearchSelected = ko.observable(!1);
  n.ProgramName = ko.observable('');
  n.CurrentPage = ko.observable(0);
  n.LastHeight = ko.observable(0);
  n.ProgramCatalog = ko.observableArray([{
    CatalogName: 'Global Catalog',
    CatalogId: 1
  },
  {
    CatalogName: 'Area Catalog',
    CatalogId: 2
  }
  ]);
  n.ColumnClicked = function (n, t) {
    paginationViewModel.ColumnClicked(t);
    programViewModel.GetPrograms()
  };
  n.ShowData = function (n) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: paginationViewModel.offset()
    }, 500);
    paginationViewModel.ShowData(n);
    programViewModel.GetPrograms()
  };
}
```

**File before**

```
function ProgramViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Programs = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectProgramForDetails = ko.observable("");
    self.SelectedProgramList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.RequestedPrograms = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedPrograms = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SearchSelected = ko.observable(false);
    self.ProgramName = ko.observable("");

    self.CurrentPage = ko.observable(0);
    self.LastHeight = ko.observable(0);

    // Default Catalog for now
    self.ProgramCatalog = ko.observableArray([
        { CatalogName: "Global Catalog", CatalogId: 1 },
        { CatalogName: "Area Catalog", CatalogId: 2 }
    ]);

    self.ColumnClicked = function (data, e) {
        paginationViewModel.ColumnClicked(e);
        programViewModel.GetPrograms();
    };

    self.ShowData = function (mode) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: paginationViewModel.offset()
        }, 500);
        paginationViewModel.ShowData(mode);

        programViewModel.GetPrograms();
    };
}
```

The problem is that minifier is not aware of keywords in scope thus  changing name of variable in same scope to existing names. When there is a `n` named variable in that scope it is renaming other function variable into n again(might can issue or might not too, not so sure).

Any minify tool that can help minify KnockoutJs files more effectively?

Comment: What is the problem? `self` is not a Knockout keyword (Knockout doesn't have any keywords).

Comment: @RoyJ, my bad self is not keyword there, but still issue was due to  changing name of variable in same scope to existing names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uglifyjs2 has mangler options which can be switched off, leaving variable names alone: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options

Comment: Thanks Billy. Let me check this one,seems what I am looking for.

Comment: Mangler was the real problem, that was changing name of variable in same scope to existing names. Solution works great.